# how to check does a method throw a exception or not?

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert, assertion

How to check does a method throw an exception or not in Junit  in `@Test` field ??

for example:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateInvalidStudentData() {
    //TODO: check does studentIdGenerator.generate(null,2); 
    //      throw IllegalArgumentException or no.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)